# Is there a name for this type of integer?

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

An integer $n$ such that $\exists$ at least one prime $p$ such that, $p|n$ but $p^2$ does not divide $n$.

i.e. : an integer with at least one prime that has a single power in the prime factorization.

Do these numbers have a special name, and have they been studied?

Comment: As you may know, the numbers not in your set are called the [**powerful numbers.**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerful_number) I do not know of a special name for the complement.

Comment: A number where all the primes have power 1 is called squarefree. But that is not the same thing you are describing here. All squarefree numbers fit your definition but $12$ is not squarefree and fits your definition.

Comment: "Divides exactly" comes into my mind : $n$ is an integer that $p$ divides exactly.

Comment: a Google search for [integers with one non repeated prime factor](https://www.google.com/search?q=integers+with+no+repeated+prime+factor&aq=f&oq=integers+with+no+repeated+prime+factor&aqs=chrome.0.57j60l2j62l3.11317&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&qscrl=1#newwindow=1&q=integers+with+one+non+repeated+prime+factor&qscrl=1) doesn't turn up anything.

Comment: Thanks everyone. André, your answer helps a lot. I didn't know those were called "powerful" numbers. I guess this is the closest answer.

Comment: I agree with André: the numbers you describe are "not powerful" or "not squarefull".

Comment: https://oeis.org/A052485

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers **not** in your set are called the [**powerful numbers**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerful_number) (There are other names.)

I do not know of a special name for the complement of the set of powerful numbers. The powerful numbers have been studied. Please see the above link for a start.

Answer (score 0):

These are sometimes called [weak numbers](http://oeis.org/A052485/internal), presumably because not weak naturals are precisely the [powerful naturals.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerful_number) However the weak terminology does not appear to be anywhere near as widely used as is the powerful terminology (e.g. Granville and Ribenboim use "not powerful"). I also recall seeing other names besides weak (e.g. impotent).